# Javascript HTML canvas tag forces directed graph crashes if there are more than 10-20 nodes, works otherwise

Tags: javascript, html, physics

I've developed a forced directed graph using javascript and html canvas using hookes law and columbs law principles. The problem I face is, it crashes if there are more than say 10-20 nodes! Otherwise works fine.. Could anyone please help?

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

    myCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    myCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    ctx.fillStyle = '#006FB9';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#006FB9';

    var time = 0;  //track total consumed time

    function Graph(){               
        this.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.height = window.innerHeight;

        this.vertices = {};
        this.forcex = {};
        this.forcey = {};
        this.stepSize = 0.0005;
        this.iteration = 0;
        this.task = null;

        this.repulsion = 200000;
        this.spring_length = 20;
    }           

    Graph.prototype.createVertex = function(name){
        var vertex = {};

        vertex.posx = Math.random() * (this.width * 0.8) + (this.width * 0.1);
        vertex.posy = Math.random() * (this.height * 0.8) + (this.height * 0.1);                
        vertex.edges = new Array();

        this.vertices[name] = vertex;               
    };

    Graph.prototype.createEdge = function(a,b){ 
        this.vertices[a].edges[b] = {'dest' : b};
        this.vertices[b].edges[a] = {'dest' : a};               
    };

    Graph.prototype.updateLayout = function(){
        for(i in g.vertices){                   
            g.forcex[i] = 0;
            g.forcey[i] = 0;
            for(j in g.vertices){                       
                if(i !== j){
                    var deltax = g.vertices[j].posx - g.vertices[i].posx;
                    var deltay = g.vertices[j].posy - g.vertices[i].posy;
                    var d2 = deltax * deltax + deltay * deltay;

                    //add jitter if d^2 is very small
                    if(d2 < 0.01){
                        deltax = 0.1 * Math.random() + 0.1;
                        deltay = 0.1 * Math.random() + 0.1;
                        d2 = deltax * deltax + deltay * deltay;                         
                    }                           

                    //columb's
                    g.forcex[i] -= (g.repulsion / d2) * deltax;
                    g.forcey[i] -= (g.repulsion / d2) * deltay;

                    //hooke's
                    if(g.vertices[i].edges[j]){
                        var distance = Math.sqrt(d2);
                        this.forcex[i] += (distance - g.spring_length) * deltax;
                        this.forcey[i] += (distance - g.spring_length) * deltay;
                    }
                }   
            }                   
        }

        for(i in g.vertices){
            //vertices
            g.vertices[i].posx += g.forcex[i] * g.stepSize;
            g.vertices[i].posy += g.forcey[i] * g.stepSize;
        }

        Graph.iteration++;              
        if(Graph.iteration > 300){
            g.quit();                   
        }       
    };

    Graph.prototype.quit = function(){
        //draw vertices
        for(i in g.vertices){

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(g.vertices[i].posx, g.vertices[i].posy, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.fill(); 
            //draw edges 
            for (j in g.vertices[i].edges){
                ctx.moveTo(g.vertices[i].posx, g.vertices[i].posy);
                    ctx.lineTo(g.vertices[g.vertices[i].edges[j].dest].posx, g.vertices[g.vertices[i].edges[j].dest].posy);
                    ctx.stroke();
            }                                       
        }       

        window.clearInterval(Graph.task);
        Graph.task = null;

        console.log('Start Time : ' + time + ' / End Time : ' + Date.now());
        };

        Graph.prototype.go = function(){
            if(this.task){
                return;
            }

            time = Date.now();  

            Graph.iteration = 0;                
            Graph.task = window.setInterval(function(){g.updateLayout();},1);
        }

        var g = new Graph();

        //invoke
        (function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                g.createVertex(i);

                if (i > 0){
                    g.createEdge('0',i);
                }
            }               
            g.go();
        })();
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "it crashes"? Does the browser crash? Is the website unresponsive? Do you get an error message in your browsers javascript console? If yes what is the error message?

Comment: *Crashes* in terms of the browser, an exception being thrown, the graph behaving weirdly ? An executable code snippet would really help...

Comment: `Graph.task = window.setInterval(function(){g.updateLayout();},1);` - so you are trying to run all those computations once each millisecond? So what....1000FPS? Try using `requestAnimationFrame` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Simply the graph does not work. I tried printing hookes and columb force values, it shows a huge negative number.

Comment: Tried with requestAnimationFrame too.. Does not work at all.. I suspect there is some issue with calculation.. Could not solve

Comment: @ram_c Did you use requestAnimationFrame *correctly*? Many people screw it up at first try by queuing the next frame at the beginning of their rendering function instead of at the end or by not queuing it at all.

Comment: Also, I _have_ to ask this: are you doing this to learn or are you looking for something that works, including existing libraries? d3.js has a pretty fast implementation of this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288 - and if you are trying to play with different force layour algorithms then you can use d3.js to abstract everything (like `requestAnimationFrame`) not related to the algorithm itself. (Here's a list of more implementations: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout)

Comment: @Philipp I am trying with requestAnimationFrame .. Will update here!

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I am trying to learn :)

Comment: @ram_c when you change the question in a way which results in the already posted answer(s) to no longer apply, then please don't update here. Ask it as a new question instead.

Answer (score 2):

You've built an algorithm with quadratic runtime. When you need `x` microseconds to process one node, it takes `x * n²` microseconds to process `n` nodes. That means the processing time raises quickly with the number of nodes to add.

However, you force the simulation to simulate a frame every 1ms using `window.setInterval`. Using `setInterval` to schedule a possible processing-intensive task is a bad idea, especially when your interval length is very short. When you have too many nodes to process in one ms, this simply can not work, because you request the browser to process the simulation faster than it is physically capable of.

To allow your application to handle a higher number of nodes at the cost of a lower number of frames per second, you could use [`window.requestAnimationFrame(function)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.requestAnimationFrame).

Replace your setInterval call with

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(g.updateLayout);
```

and at the end of `g.updateLayout` place the same line to request the next frame as soon as the browser finished drawing the last one.

Comment: "When you need x microseconds to process one node, it takes x * n² seconds to process n nodes."  ... I think you intended to use the same unit of measure there seconds vs microseconds.

Comment: You might mention that the minimum setInterval delay is 1000/60=16.67 ms -- and that's assuming all the animation can be accomplished in 17ms. Time test your animation and increase the delay above 17ms if your animation takes longer to render. Having said that, you will be better off using Philipp's suggestion: requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work well.. It looks like the design is failing